# Cannot connect to database (free host somee.com)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I recently created a .aspx-website for a school project and it is hosted for free on www.somee.com. Also included in the host's free package is a database (SQLServer).
I don't have SQLServer at home but i need to use the database so I ran a query to create all tables needed. So far everything worked, the database exists (I see this in somee.com's member area) and my website can be visited.

However, I want to Insert/Updata/Delete data from my code behind. I got the following connection-string from my host:

```
workstation id=sskDatabase.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=****;pwd=****;data source=sskDatabase.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=sskDatabase
```

Unfortunately it's not working.

In my web.config:

and my code behind:

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
string commandString = String.Format("INSERT INTO Mitglied (Position_Id, Username, Passwort, EMail, Beitrittsdatum, aktiv) VALUES ({0},'{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}',{5})", 0, mitglied.Username, mitglied.Password, mitglied.EMail, DateTime.Now, 1);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
sqlCommand.CommandText = commandString;
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlCommand.Connection.Close();
}
```

It crashes at sqlCommand.Connection.Open(); with the following error message:

Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=119; handshake=14883;

Any ideas why I can't connect to my database?

Comment: Contact their administrator? Normally you should not be able to connect - the database should be hired behind a firewall, likely they changed the default port number at least.

Comment: Good question. I had a similar problem, but i couldn't solve it.

Comment: My problem is that i have the free hosting package and they usually don't answer questions of people like me^^

Comment: Well, i took me less than a minute to get the information out of their support documents. I suggest you try reading them. They are on their website.

Answer (score 1):

Contact their support? Normally you should not be able to connect - the database should be hired behind a firewall, likely they changed the default port number at least.

This here is not a replacement for your host's support, you know.

Comment: To the downvoter: I just contacted their support and ggor the answer. I tis on the website.

Comment: I've tried to conteact them but they didn't reply and on their website they explicitely say that they do not always reply to users of the free hosting package. So what did you find out? (I did not downvote you, I'm thankful for every answer)

Comment: Well, they do have exquisite documentation on the website. Reading helps. Support in the menu, Help System linked in the page. How to has an area "Manage MS SQL Database" and that has a topic "connect to database" that tells you where to find your connection information in the user interface.

Comment: Yes this connection information they give me there is exactly the connection string I am trying to use ...

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio to validate things work. Try telnet to port 1433 to see whether you get any connection.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying it from your school labs? I had the same problem with the same host. In my project it was the school ***firewall*** that prevent me from connecting to the database. It's a long shot you can **try to connect from your own network** (at home or by using your phone as access point) and see if it still happening.

Comment: I think it's an optional answer, it solved my issue after I tried so many other (and much more complicated) solutions. I did suggest a way check and solve the issue. (for sure better than "read the documentation").

Comment: I think it is an answer but unfortunately it didn't work for me :( Thanks though and let the haters hate :D

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check if the database server is available, easily you can use a ping command to your ip server adresse.

If the databse server is available you could check if the port of the instance is available, the default is 1433.
To do this you can use telnet command like in this example :

```
telnet XXX.XX.XX.XX 1433
```

A important thing that you have to know is that a SQL Server service browser is looking for a client call in the server side, it's this service which receives the call and able the communication. You have to make sure that this service is working too.

Comment: Thank you, the ping to sskDatabase.mssql.somee.com does work. But I'm not quite sure how to do this telnet stuff... I've tried to run "telnet sskdatabase.mssql.somee.com 1433" in cmd. I probably misunderstood you can you clarify please?

Comment: telnet able you to connect and create a session to the remote server. I'm not sure to know if the telnet accept the dns name in parameter, you can try to get the ip adress by a command ping (the ip adress of the remote server is indicate when you execute the ping command) and try telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 1433. If it's work you'll see a command prompt and no error throwed. To know if the port is open you have just to verify if the telnet has worked.

Comment: If the command doesn't work you can ask your support to check if the firewall is configured to accept your call (from your ip adresse) to the port of the sql server instance you try to connect.